# Dynamically add methods to a class in Python 3.0

Tags: python-3.x, python

I'm trying to write a Database Abstraction Layer in Python which lets you construct SQL statments using chained function calls such as:

```
results = db.search("book")
          .author("J. K. Rowling")
          .price("<40.00")
          .title("Harry")
          .execute()
```

but I am running into problems when I try to dynamically add the required methods to the db class.

Here is the important parts  of my code:

```
import inspect

def myName():
    return inspect.stack()[1][3]

class Search():

    def __init__(self, family):
        self.family = family
        self.options = ['price', 'name', 'author', 'genre']
        #self.options is generated based on family, but this is an example
        for opt in self.options:
            self.__dict__[opt] = self.__Set__
        self.conditions = {}

    def __Set__(self, value):
        self.conditions[myName()] = value
        return self

    def execute(self):
        return self.conditions
```

However, when I run the example such as:

```
print(db.search("book").price(">4.00").execute())
```

outputs:

```
{'__Set__': 'harry'}
```

Am I going about this the wrong way? Is there a better way to get the name of the function being called or to somehow make a 'hard copy' of the function?

Comment: May I ask *why* you are trying to reinvent SQLAlchemy?

Comment: I actually quite commonly try to code my own libraries which replicate those that already exist so that I can learn more about the language and get a better feel for how the more advanced parts come together :)

Comment: OK, a learning exercise, that is a good reason. Although in this case I think reading the SQLAlchemy source code will be a good start. ORM's are complex and magical.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply add the search functions (methods) **after the class is created**:

```
class Search:  # The class does not include the search methods, at first
    def __init__(self):
        self.conditions = {}

def make_set_condition(option):  # Factory function that generates a "condition setter" for "option"
    def set_cond(self, value):
        self.conditions[option] = value
        return self
    return set_cond

for option in ('price', 'name'):  # The class is extended with additional condition setters
    setattr(Search, option, make_set_condition(option))

Search().name("Nice name").price('$3').conditions  # Example
{'price': '$3', 'name': 'Nice name'}
```

**PS**: This class has an `__init__()` method that does not have the `family` parameter (the condition setters are dynamically added at runtime, but are added to the class, not to each instance separately).  If `Search` **objects with different condition setters** need to be created, then the following variation on the above method works (the `__init__()` method has a `family` parameter):

```
import types

class Search:  # The class does not include the search methods, at first

    def __init__(self, family):
        self.conditions = {}
        for option in family:  # The class is extended with additional condition setters
            # The new 'option' attributes must be methods, not regular functions:
            setattr(self, option, types.MethodType(make_set_condition(option), self))

def make_set_condition(option):  # Factory function that generates a "condition setter" for "option"
    def set_cond(self, value):
        self.conditions[option] = value
        return self
    return set_cond

>>> o0 = Search(('price', 'name'))  # Example
>>> o0.name("Nice name").price('$3').conditions
{'price': '$3', 'name': 'Nice name'}
>>> dir(o0)  # Each Search object has its own condition setters (here: name and price)
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'conditions', 'name', 'price']

>>> o1 = Search(('director', 'style'))
>>> o1.director("Louis L").conditions  # New method name
{'director': 'Louis L'}
>>> dir(o1)  # Each Search object has its own condition setters (here: director and style)
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'conditions', 'director', 'style']
```

Reference: http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods

---

If you really need search methods that know about the name of the attribute they are stored in, you can simply set it in `make_set_condition()` with

```
       set_cond.__name__ = option  # Sets the function name
```

(just before the `return set_cond`).  Before doing this, method `Search.name` has the following name:

```
>>> Search.price
<function set_cond at 0x107f832f8>
```

after setting its `__name__` attribute, you get a different name:

```
>>> Search.price
<function price at 0x107f83490>
```

Setting the method name this way makes possible error messages involving the method easier to understand.

Comment: +1. You're right. I was being too clever. There's nothing special about these condition setter methods that requires them to be created on each instance.

Comment: I was assuming these methods where to be be set automatically from the schema, maybe I was assuming too much. :-)

Comment: According to the problem description the method names will vary based on the family, so setting the names on the class will result in either missing names for some families, or all the names for every family.

Comment: @EthanFurman: You're right. I guessed (perhaps incorrectly) that family was actually not a proper `__init__()` parameter because `__init__()` was always called with the same family, in a given program. I added a PS that stresses this point and gives a solution that gives each `Search` instance its own family of possible option searches.

Answer (score 5):

Here is some working code to get you started (not the whole program you were trying to write, but something that shows how the parts can fit together):

```
class Assign:

    def __init__(self, searchobj, key):
        self.searchobj = searchobj
        self.key = key

    def __call__(self, value):
        self.searchobj.conditions[self.key] = value
        return self.searchobj

class Book():

    def __init__(self, family):
        self.family = family
        self.options = ['price', 'name', 'author', 'genre']
        self.conditions = {}

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if key in self.options:
            return Assign(self, key)
        raise RuntimeError('There is no option for: %s' % key)

    def execute(self):
        # XXX do something with the conditions.
        return self.conditions

b = Book('book')
print(b.price(">4.00").author('J. K. Rowling').execute())
```

Comment: Each and every search creates an `Assign` instance, which is a bit time and memory heavy. :)  Is there any advantage of this approach compared to the direct "add methods after class creation" method outlined in my answer?

Comment: @EOL This approach is how Python itself works and it is a common idiom.  For example, Python creates a new BoundMethod instance every time you make a method call such as ``a.m(x)``.  The OP is trying to learn how Python works and it is appropriate to teach \_\_call\_\_ for calls and \_\_getattr\_\_ for dynamic dotted lookup.  That is what they are for.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, `__getattr__` and `__call__` are indeed important to know when it comes to dynamic lookup.  I'm not sure this is what the OP needs, though: I understand that he wants to define non-dynamical class attributes, instead of dynamical instance attributes.  No?  (That pretty much sums up the two different approaches taken in our answers, I think.)

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, you are not adding anything to the class, you are adding it to the instance.

Secondly, you don't need to access **dict**. The `self.__dict__[opt] = self.__Set__` is better done with `setattr(self, opt, self.__Set__)`.

Thirdly, don't use `__xxx__` as attribute names. Those are reserved for Python-internal use.

Fourthly, as you noticed, Python is not easily fooled. The internal name of the method you call is still `__Set__`, even though you access it under a different name. :-) The name is set when you define the method as a part of the `def` statement.

You probably want to create and set the options methods with a metaclass. You also might want to actually create those methods instead of trying to use one method for all of them. If you really want to use only one `__getattr__` is the way, but it can be a bit fiddly, I generally recommend against it. Lambdas or other dynamically generated methods are probably better.

Comment: Here is the reference about `__*__` names: http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers

Comment: @EOL I've always thought of '__xxx__' names as 'private' properties or methods of a class that don't/can't get called from outside of it? Is there any convention which you *are* supposed to use for these?

Comment: @Ben: Yes, there is a convention, which is very similar to the notation reserved by Python: it's `__xxx` (no trailing "dunder")–same reference as above.

Comment: @EOL: No, that's not a convention, that's what triggers name mangling. Different.

Comment: @Ben: The convention to mark something as internal is to start it with one underscore. Having two underscores triggers a name mangling that can be useful to avoid naming clashes.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: I don't see the problem with referring to `__xxx` as "Python's convention for 'private' methods", or "convention for name mangling triggering".  I indeed see a difference, but it's between "convention for 'private' methods" (`__xxx`) and "name mangling" (which is added on top of the convention).  Ben's question was about the convention, but it is indeed interesting to note that Python gives it more expressive power by mangling names.  Noting that there is a notion of "semi-private", unmangled method name (`_xxx`) is also interesting.

Comment: @EOL: The point is that leading double underscores is not a convention at all. It triggers name mangling to avoid name clashes. It actually does something, and it's not a convention. The *convention* for flagging that something is "private"/internal/use at own risk is one leading underscore.